# Pushout of unital non commutative algebras

Tags: category-theory, noncommutative-algebra

I like to know if there is a pushout in the category of non commutative alegbras with unit and if the answer is "yes", who is it?

Comment: Yes. It's a variant of the amalgamated free product, adapted to algebras.

Comment: @QiaochuYuan, do you have some reference? I would like to check the construction carefully and if your reference has it with $\ast$-algebras, it would be better. I'd really appreciate that

Comment: You might not find a reference that's amenable to careful checking. Careful proofs of a theorem like this are more likely to be done in much more generality-for arbitrary "categories of algebras," for instance.

Comment: ok @KevinCarlson. Well, it would be ok if I just see who is this algebra and how I can define the morphisms involved in the diagrams.

Answer (score 5):

Given unital $R$-algebras $A\leftarrow B\to C$, the pushout $A \star_B C$ is generated as an $R$-algebra by generators of $A$ and of $C$, modulo the union of the relations in $A$ and in $C$, as well as further relations identifying the two resulting images of each element of $B$. This immediately gives the canonical maps from $A$ and $C$. You can describe this construction as a quotient of the free $R$-module on words with letters from $A$ and $C$, if you like.